# How to get SSIS HTTP connection "use proxy" to work without credentials

Tags: ssis, proxy, sql-server-data-tools

**Is the "Use Proxy" option on an HTTP Connection in SSIS 2012 broken when not using credentials?**

I have a Web Service task in SSIS 2012 that works well normally.  When I modify its HTTP Connection to use a proxy without credentials, it seems to ignore my choice and not use the proxy at all.   When I specify credientials, it then uses the proxy.

To figure this out, I set it up both ways, and ran Fiddler **with capture off**.  Fiddler with capture off will still show traffic specifically routed through it as it acts as a proxy.

Below are the screenshots with details.  You should be able to reproduce this.

First, I note the port that Fiddler is set up with:

[image]

Then, I leave Fiddler running but **not** capturing:

[image]

Then I set up the HTTP connection to use the local Fiddler proxy explicitly:

[image]

Then I run the Web Service task, and note that nothing shows up in Fiddler.

[image]

This tells me that, in this case, **SSIS isn't actually using the Web Proxy as I asked it to.  Anyone know why not?**

To be sure it is working otherwise, I then set up the HTTP connection to use the local Fiddler proxy explicitly, but this time with credentials.

[image]

Then I run the Web service task, and note that the request now appears in Fiddler, as expected.  So what was wrong in the earlier example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only way is to make the user name and password blank, but leave the box checked.  I was surprised when this worked.  I am not sure if this is related to how my particular proxy is set up, so your results may vary.